# Load Hive bucketed table with flat file incrementally

Tags: load, hive, bucket

I have a flat file person.txt, which I get everyday with following fields
id,name,state,dob

I have one Hive table -Person which is partitioned by state and bucketed by Id (30 buckets).
1)Is there a way to directly load person.txt into Person , so that 30 buckets are created?
  Currently I have an intermediate table which acts as a Staging layer from where data is loaded into    Person

2) I receive person.txt everyday in incremental way. Is there a way to load Person in incremental way so that 30 buckets are always maintained. Insert overwrite will clear everything when I write from Staging table, due to which I have to maintain a full history of person.txt in Staging and obviously whole thing exists in Person and due to replication factor of 3. 1 TB becomes 6 TB.

Any pointers, will help

Answer (score 0):

Add 2nd partition to your table something like batchid after the state partition.
provide the batch run number as partition value everytime you load the new file so that new file goes in new partition and creates 30 buckets for every load.

> insert overwrite table PERSON partition(state,batchid) select ...

OR

> LOAD data local inpath  overwrite into table PERSON partition(batchid=1);